# Calendar-app number display in Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, calendar

Is there a setting that can be activated to allow the Ubuntu Calendar-app icon in the Unity bar, to show the current date?

At the moment is shows the number 28, which is good. However, it would be great if it showed the actual date at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

As you already state in your question: It is an icon.

There is no setting, that would make an icon change automatically every day. Icons are generally fixed.

Comment: OK so would it be a good idea to replace it with a generally fixed item?

Comment: @unknown user: I personally do not mind seeing always 28 as the icon for the calendar app, but feel free to submit your feedback on the application on launchpad :)

Comment: true it is not bad seeing the 28. However, on my Ubuntu system I have a calendar app that has an icon at the top of the screen and displays the current do. How good would that look in the Unity bar. i think it would look great. I will look into launchpad, cheers.